# How to chain forms one into another (Angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to implement an enrollment process. There are 4 forms, one with the basic info, the next is about location preferences, and so on. I created a component which uses the data service to communicate with the backend. This main component has 4 child components which contain the corresponding forms. The first form creates an object, and I need this object in the second form. The output of the second form is needed in the third form, this goes with the last form as well. I would like to set up routing as well, but it may not be necessary.

`<app-basicinfo-form
  (output)="onDataChange($event)"></app-basicinfo-form>`
This is how I get the output from the first form to the main component. I would like to pass this output to the second form from the main component.
`<app-locationpref-form
  [object]="..."></<app-locationpref-form>>`
What should I write to that spot? And how can I achieve that the forms are rendered one after another?

This is from the module I created for the components.
`const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'enrollment',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: EnrollmentComponent },
      { path: 'basicinfo', component: BasicinfoFormComponent },
      { path: 'location', component: LocationFormComponent },
      { path: 'role', component: RoleFormComponent },
      { path: 'tools', component: ToolsFormComponent }
    ]
  }
];`

Do I need something here? How can I pass the object between the forms?

Comment: You need to keep the form data in state so all of your components can access it. See: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use Angular Material, I think stepper control will meet your need. Also Tab control with forms in each tab and buttons navigating between forms can be helpful.

See the links below:

https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

I have personally used both for my clients.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check them out.